# Gmail smtp email sending fails with my new domain

Tags: email, meteor, smtp, gmail, meteor-up

I can't make gmail smtp send email from my Meteor website when I use my new *.ca domain. Everything works fine if I use another domain.

This is the mup.json mail url:

```
"MAIL_URL": "smtp://user%40domain.ca:password@smtp.gmail.com:465"
```

If i replace that line by another working website that i created, it works:

```
"MAIL_URL": "smtp://user%40domain2.com:password2@smtp.gmail.com:465"
```

1. I'm clueless as of how to troubleshoot that. Would that be the domain? I need your help.

EDIT
The log of the error is: AuthError: Invalid login

Answer (score 0):

It turned out I had to allow access for less secure apps in my google apps account, as explained in this google support answer:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

That fixed the issue.